# Enable adb debug over TCP/IP on Android AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I've build Android AOSP from `master` as described on the project docs https://source.android.com/setup/build/devices#960hikey

I've changed the mk file https://android.googlesource.com/device/linaro/hikey/+/refs/heads/master/hikey960.mk#33 to add the property overrides like shown in the picture:

[image: hikey960.mk]

Flashed everything to the device and tried to connect to it like this:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb connect 192.168.196.78:5555
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
failed to connect to '192.168.196.78:5555': Connection refused
```

I've looked everywhere on how to enable it on the target device without lucky.

Can someone point me what may be wrong?

USB connection works perfectly and I don't have anything blocking the port like a firewall or proxy. It is all on my local wifi network...

**Before you answer**, please note that this is not a regular smartphone where ADB works out-of-the-box. It is Android AOSP on Hikey 960 (Google's reference board for AOSP).

Thank you! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I don't actually need to change AOSP code at all. All I need is to boot the device with the USB-C cable and do the following:

```
$ adb shell
hikey960:/ $ su
hikey960:/ # setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555
hikey960:/ # exit
hikey960:/ $ exit
$ adb reboot
$ adb connect 192.168.196.77:5555
connected to 192.168.196.77:5555
```

(after reboot don't forget to remove the USB-C cable!)

So, in other words, we were setting the wrong prop. All props that need to persistent across reboot are prefixed with `persist.`

I hope it help if anyone fall in the same situation.

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether you selected a build configuration where ADB is enabled by default (`-eng`, `-userdebug`). Otherwise you would have to enable it while Android is running, which requires a connected display and an input device. Usually this can be done by navigating into the settings and clicking on the build number multiple times.
- Check your network connection from host (`ping 192.168.196.78`) and target (`ping 192.168.196.?`).
- Check `logcat` for error messages on the target.
- Try restarting the `adbd` daemon on the target (`sudo stop adbd && sudo start adbd`). Note: obviously requires additional non-adb connection.

Comment: The build was made using `hikey960-userdebug` which I assume ADB should be there... If you look at the picture, I've set `service.adb.tcp.port` prop which should put the device on tcp state. However, it looks like it is being ignored. The USB path works perfectly. It connects just fine. The TCP which always return "Connection refused".

Answer (score 0):

I found this in original AOSP source code:

```
device/google/cuttlefish/shared/device.mk:
  57  PRODUCT_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES += \
  58:     persist.adb.tcp.port=5555 \
```

Answer (score -1):

$ adb kill-server

$ adb tcpip 5555

** daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

$ adb connect 192.168.2.18:5555

*connected to 192.168.2.18:5555

Comment: > adb tcpip 5555

Looks like you didnt read the post properly :(